# iPhone ViewController loading as UIModal and UINavigation - how to differentiate

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Maybe someone can drop me a pointer.  I've got a `UIViewController` that is being served up as both a `UIModalViewController` and pushed onto the view stack via a `UINavigationController` -  **depending on where the user launches the view** from within the app.  I want to load two different HTTP Requests based on how the user loads the view, so I need a conditional in `viewDidLoad` to determine where the view came from in order to call the correct request.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there already. Rather than your UIViewController being aware of how it was launched, I suggest that you have the various places in your code which create the view controller configure it at or after creation with some information regarding its desired behaviour -- for example, configuring which URL it should download. Then, in viewDidLoad or elsewhere in your view controller, you can just do the correct thing based on how your UIViewController was configured.

So, as a solid example, have an init method for your VC take as a parameter the desired URL (or have it settable as a property). Then later on in viewDidLoad (or wherever you like) your VC can do the correct thing without being 'polluted' with details it shouldn't really care about (such as how it was pushed onto the UI etc.)

Comment: P.S. Thanks for asking a well stated, easy to understand question :)

Comment: Wow, I never even looked at it that way.  Simple enough!  I was so stuck on differences in view transitions that I didn't even think about to just pass it along on create.  This will require a little change in my passing VC, but I like the approach:)

P.S. Thanks for a straightforward answer that makes me work a little bit :)

Comment: If I go the route of making it a settable property, do I still need to include the URL handling in the init method?  Could I not just create the VC and then call setURL (as long as its a property)

Comment: Yes, if it's a settable property, no need to change your init method. Just make sure you remember to the set the property right after you init the instance!